# PHP built in web server with multiple sites?

Tags: php, zend-framework

**Does the PHP built in web server allow multiple instances/sites?**

*Background on the project skeleton*
I am working through Zend for the first time via Chrisopher Valles' tutorial.. with a slight difference.  He uses Vagrant to instantiate a VBox instance, and I'm working locally in Ubuntu 12.x LTS...

https://github.com/christophervalles for more details on the Vagrant box...

**I want to utilize the internal PHP 5.5 server if possible, but getting an error when (of course) running the 2nd call.**

Is the **best/usual** solution to have the core service be on some variable port when in development, and run the web client on port 80?

I'd, of course, need to rewrite some of my client's code to point to the new port, but would the Zend Service need a rewrite anywhere?  I'd say no.

**Starting up my site's core/api services Zend project :**

```
 >php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php
 PHP 5.5.10-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 Development Server started at Day Date Time
 Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080
 Document root is /home/core_site/public
 Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

**Starting up my site's web client, that talks to the first server:**

```
 >php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php
 [Day Date] Failed to listen on 0.0.0.0:8080 (reason: Address already in use)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could just use a different port

```
 php -S 0.0.0.0:8081 -t public/ public/index.php
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I'm aware and will probably do this for now.. but hoping there's a more elegant way so that I don't have to remember the port(s) in the config/app itself.

Might have to just do a full apache instance and setup a multi site.. :(

Comment: probably best, apache is really not all that difficult to configure that way

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reading my book!
About your question, Andrew is right about using a different port. As far as I know you cannot do domain name based hosts on the built in php server. If you don't want to use different ports each time you should look into using apache or nginx.

If you go with nginx and php you can re-use the config files I use for the Vagrant machine so you don't have to do everything from scratch. Essentially the OS on the Vagrant machine is a Ubuntu 12.04 (the same as yours) so shouldn't be hard to re-use the configs :D

You can check out the php.ini and the nginx vhosts used on Vagrant [here](https://github.com/christophervalles/ZF2-Vagrant/tree/master/cookbooks/custom/templates/default).

Cheers!

Comment: You can use domain names, but you would need to update your `/etc/hosts` file to point to `0.0.0.0 my.domain.com` Then execute `/path/to/php -S my.domain.com:80 -t /path/to/web/root /path/to/router.php` However you can not use the same port for a different domain on the same ip, as it would conflict with the environment. `my.domain.com + my.domain2.com = 0.0.0.0:80` the system would not know which server was requested unless you added domain name sniffing to the router script and use the same router for all domains. Which still applies to a single instance of the builtin server.